# How to read yahoo weather JSON data with Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2295424

```
{
"units":
{"temperature":"F","speed":"mph","distance":"mi","pressure":"in"},
"location":{"location_id":"INXX0075","city":"Madras","state_abbreviation":"*","country_abbreviation":"IN","elevation":49,"latitude":13,"longitude":80.18000000000001},
"wind":{"speed":12.00000000000000,"direction":"E"},
"atmosphere":{"humidity":"23","visibility":"4.35","pressure":"29.77","rising":"steady"},
"url":"http:\/\/weather.yahoo.com\/forecast\/INXX0075.html","logo":"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/a\/i\/us\/nt\/ma\/ma_nws-we_1.gif","astronomy":{"sunrise":"06:20","sunset":"18:19"},"condition":{"text":"Sunny","code":"32","image":"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/a\/i\/us\/we\/52\/32.gif","temperature":93.00000000000000},

"forecast":[{
"day":"Today","condition":"Mostly Clear","high_temperature":"91","low_temperature":"69"},{"day":"Tomorrow","condition":"Partly Cloudy","high_temperature":"90","low_temperature":"70"}
]}
```

I want to display "forecast"

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and ask an unambiguous question. "forecast" contains several things to display, and what you mean by "display" is not clear either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2295424",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      console.log( data.forecast[0].day );
      }
 });
```

In data.forecast[0].day you replace "day" with whatever property you need.

Comment: No result console.log( data.forecast[0].day )

Comment: @Srinivas Tamada
>Why console.log()
Just because I'm used to it. That means you could use alert(), or $(#myElement).html( data.forecast[0].day );
BTW, in case you don't know where "console.log" comes from, you shoudl try "Firebug" on Firefox or "Dragonfly" in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

```
console.debug("initYahooWeather starting");
    var urlYahooWeather = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2295424";

    var urlFlickr = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?jsoncallback=?&w=2295424";
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: urlFlickr,
        success: function(data){
            console.dir(data);
            console.dir(data.forecast);
            // here you have to navigate the array 

        },
        error: function(msg){
            console.debug("error contacting JSON server side component...");
            console.debug(msg);
        }
    });

    console.debug("initYahooWeather stop");
```

I tried myself but with jQuery 1.5 I receive a parse error: I dunno why, the code should be ok.

Mazi